# ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE() not working in phpmyadmin sql

Tags: mysql

I have dates in `varchar` type like:

- 201601
- 201602
- 201603
- 201701
- 201702 and so on

I am trying to view all my records where the dates are in ascending order. So I am using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM emp_pp GROUP BY YEARMM ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(YEARMM,'%Y%m')
```

Here `YEARMM` is my column name. The query isn't working properly when I run it. Instead I keep getting all these notices:

```
Incorrect datetime value: '201601' for function str_to_date
Incorrect datetime value: '201602' for function str_to_date...
```

Why is that? Please help me

Comment: You cannot use STR_TO_DATE() over incomplete date, without day part. From the other side you may order by current column value - it will give the same ordering.

Comment: I wonder why you thought you had to convert yearmm?

Comment: Order by default INT it's going to be just the same value as your structure is YEARMONTH. `SELECT * FROM emp_pp GROUP BY YEARMM ORDER BY YEARMM DESC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Akina, `STR_TO_DATE` function [requires enough data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to generate at minimum a full date value to work correctly. You do not have that (you can not have a date 2016-02-00, for example).

What you do have is a numerical Year and Month integer,  201601, 201602, 201603, 201701 etc. which orders exactly as you want by standard numerical ordering so all you need to do is remove the `STR_TO_DATE` part entirely:

```
SELECT * FROM emp_pp GROUP BY YEARMM ORDER BY YEARMM ASC /* Oldest date first */
```

Of note:

- `SELECT *`  is highly inefficient. You should name each column you want to collect.
- Column names in SQL should not be upper case, as this is hard to read with the correct case syntax, SQL column should be only lower case; `yearmm` would be more readable in your SQL code.